# clang-format closing bracket on a new line

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have code that looks like this:

```
EXPECT_EQ(
    subsystem->previousTouchscreenState,
    expectedTouchscreenState
);
```

When I run `clang-format`, it reformats the snippet to look like this:

```
EXPECT_EQ(
    subsystem->previousTouchscreenState,
    expectedTouchscreenState );
```

This is quite counterintuitive; I'd like my multi-line function invocations (although `EXPECT_EQ` is a macro in this case) to have the closing round bracket on its own line, indented to the level of the name of the function, as it is in the first snippet.

How do I accomplish this with `clang-format`?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: looks like they are going to add it in the future https://reviews.llvm.org/D33029

Comment: @devalone why not add this as an answer?

Comment: @eike, they haven't added the feature yet or am I missing something?

Comment: @devalone I don't think so, but because of this, I would consider "it's not possible, but it will be added" a fine answer to this question.

Comment: @eike *can be added. I don't think it's an answer.

Comment: @devalone even without the perspective of the feature being added, the information that what OP requests is impossible right now would constitute an answer in my book. But it is up to you of course and if you think differently that is fine by me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get clang format to put closing parenthesis of multiline function calls on separate lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689027/get-clang-format-to-put-closing-parenthesis-of-multiline-function-calls-on-separ)

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like my multi-line function invocations (although EXPECT_EQ is a macro in this case) to have the closing round bracket on its own line, indented to the level of the name of the function, as it is in the first snippet.
>
> How do I accomplish this with clang-format?

That option does not seem to be added yet; either wait or get involved in the clang open source project.

Edit:
As pointed out by Catskul, DCzajkowski and Dwayne in the comments:
https://reviews.llvm.org/D109557 was accepted

Comment: Warning, clang-format is known for having impassable standards for contributions: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#adding-additional-style-options Such an option has been developed and reviewed, but is hanging in limbo: https://reviews.llvm.org/D33029

Comment: There is an active PR here that was accepted: https://reviews.llvm.org/D109557

Comment: 2022-01-17 https://reviews.llvm.org/D109557 was accepted and closed, adding AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent, which I anticipate will be in the next clang format release.

Answer (score 1):

I found one workaround. If you put a comment at the end of the last argument, clang-format (or any tool) should not fold back the closing parenthesis.

```
EXPECT_EQ(
    subsystem->previousTouchscreenState,
    expectedTouchscreenState //
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> BAS_BlockIndent (in configuration: BlockIndent) Always break after an
> open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line. Closing
> brackets will be placed on a new line. E.g.:

You can use `AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent`

There is more information here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignafteropenbracket

Comment: Note that in `clang-format --version` 10, this fails with error `error: unknown enumerated scalar AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent`. It appears to be available in `clang-format` version 14 or later only. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70844055/4561887).