# Wrap brace (and/or parentheses) after long function signature in clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm trying to achieve the following format for short functions:

```
void shortFunctionDecl(int x, int y) {
    // ...
}
```

But if the line is too long, I would like it to overflow like this (and not bin pack the arguments)

```
void longerFunctionDecl(
    int longName, 
    int longName2,
    int longName3
) { // I would also be ok if the paren were on the previous line and the brace on this one
    // ...
}
```

Currently code ends up like this and it's annoying to read

```
void longerFunctionDecl(
    int longName, 
    int longName2,
    int longName3) { 
    // code is at the same indentation level as the args, hard to read.
}
```

I've been trying to place around with some of the BraceWrapping settings but it looks like there are only Multiline settings for control statements. Is it possible to do what I want in `clang-format`? FWIW, it seems like the parenthesis breaks are [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689027/get-clang-format-to-put-closing-parenthesis-of-multiline-function-calls-on-separ) but I wonder if the brace breaks might be? Really not sure.

Here's my `.clang-format` file. I've marked the relevant section, but included the entire thing for completeness.

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Always
ColumnLimit: 120
AccessModifierOffset: -3
# Relevant portion:
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new option `AlignAfterOpenBracket`: `BlockIndent` was added (2022-01-17) in the approved code review https://reviews.llvm.org/D109557, which is in clang format [LLVM 14.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-14.0.0-rc1) or later.

```
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent: If set, it will always break after an
open bracket, if the parameters don't fit on a single line. Closing brackets
will be placed on a new line.
```